# meta with max-width(for image) not working

Tags: html, css

if image is 100x100 in any scale.

whenever I use this:

```
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.0,
width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

with this:

```
<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 900px) {a{
    margin-left:0%;
    max-width::100%; 

}}

</style>
```

and this:

```
 <body>
    <a href="">
    <img src="nod.png"></div></a></body>
```

I get the fully sized image(100x100) on my phone. And if I remove the meta tag. the mobile adjusts the image itself(e.g. 10x10) according to device. How can I acheieve image self resizing(10x10) with this meta tag?

Comment: Do you really have **`::`** after `max-width` in the CSS? It should be just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.remove the minimum-scale
2.set maximum-scale to '0.0'

that should do it...